# How do I group strings together to create a text "blob" by group?

Tags: r, nlp, string-concatenation

I have a data frame with 100,000+ records. Each record is a product with several data points and a free text field that explains a particular issue that a product has. This is an example of a data frame that I have, let's call it: "`df`"

```
product   class     subclass     issue
prod1     R         A1           problem has to do with x, y, and z
prod1     R         A2           this product has something wrong with z
prod2     L         B1           there was no problem with this
prod2     L         B2           part that went bad
prod2     L         B1           this was improperly installed
prod3     R         A1           problem has to with parts a, b, and z
.
.
.
```

I've used

```
df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(blob = str_c(df%issue, collapse = " "))
```

to try and get to:

```
product     blob
prod1       problem has to do with x, y, and z this product has something wrong with z
prod2       there was no problem with this part that went bad this was improperly installed
prod3       problem has to with parts a, b, and z
```

I'm doing more cleaning of the text before I get to this point - removing stopwords, punctuation, lemmatizing etc.

Since I want to group, I've been using `dplyr`. I've tried using `paste` to group by and concatenate and I've tried `str_c` from `stringr` because I saw it performs better. But I'm not sure if it is a performance issue because I'm trying to group and concatenate over 100,000 strings?

I will also want to look at a blob by class and subclass also, hence why I'm using dplyr.

Once I get this proper grouping, I will be able to look at a number of different things, term frequencies, LDA by group, and so on.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `df%` is not needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(product) %>% 
    mutate(blob = str_c(issue, collapse = " "))
```